# What is "date"? "Get-Command date" throws CommandNotFoundException

Tags: powershell

`date` working:

```
PS> date

Saturday, June 10, 2017 9:10:11 AM
```

But `Get-Command date` throws exception:

```
PS> Get-Command date
Get-Command : The term 'date' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Command date
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (date:String) [Get-Command], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCommandCommand
```

Also `Get-Alias date` throws exception:

```
PS> Get-Alias date
Get-Alias : This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name 'date' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Alias date
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (date:String) [Get-Alias], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAliasCommand
```

`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` is "5.1.15063.296" on Windows 10.

The `date` seems not to be a cmdlet, function, script file, operable program or alias. So, what is the `date`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The PowerShell CommandDiscovery API uses [the following precedence order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence) to resolve command names to commands:

1. Alias
2. Function
3. Cmdlet
4. Native Windows commands

If the command name does *not* contain a dash or a slash, and no command has been found after exhausting the last option in the list above, it'll try again, but [with `Get-` prepended](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/02b5f357a20e6dee9f8e60e3adb9025be3c94490/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandDiscovery.cs#L1193).

For this reason, the `Get` verb is also known as the default command verb.

This works for any `Get-*` command for which there's no collision with existing alias, function or cmdlet names, or native executable in `$env:path`, like:

```
Alias
Item
ChildItem
```

... and so on.

---

If you ever again wonder why a command get's resolved in a certain way, you can use the [`Trace-Command` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command) to get debug-level information from the powershell engine:

```
Trace-Command -Expression { date } -Name Command* -Option All -PSHost
```

`Command*` will, in this context, match the `CommandSearch` and `CommandDiscovery` routines and show you exactly which steps powershell takes to resolve the command name `date`

Comment: Thank you for your quick and detailed answer! Thanks to that, I understood that the `date` was an unknown term for PowerShell, however, for the "Get- prepended" feature, `Get-date` was invoked.

Answer (score 8):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476385/45375), which explains the command-discovery process well:

**That `Get-Command` is unaware of the default-verb logic and therefore doesn't report the same command that is actually *executed* when the given command name is used is an *inconsistency that should be fixed***, because that is its very purpose when given a command name.

- As an aside: The `-All` option allows you to see additional commands of the same name with lower precedence, but even wit `-All` `date` isn't found (and, if it were, it should be listed *first*, in line with reporting it as the *effective* command, without `-All`).

Similarly, `Get-Help` and `-?` are also unaware of the default-verb logic:

- `date -?` and `Get-Help date` do not return `Get-Date's` help; instead, they *list* help topics that *contain the word* `date`.

I've created an [issue in the PowerShell GitHub repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3987).

Comment: Nice. Had a look at the source, looks like `Get-Command` actually invokes the CommandDiscovery class correctly, but omits resolved command from the ouput, perhaps oversight/forgetfulness from the developers side :-P